# Problem with filling an Hashmap java

Tags: java, hashmap

Hello
I want to fill an hashmap with value => 
key :idissue
value:arraylist (list of assignee)
The problem that my function return the same liste of assignee for all my issues:
My map{10700=[x,y,z], 10500=[x,y,z],10600=[x,y,z].......

Or the result should be like this:
My map{10700=[x,y,z], 10500=[w,v,q,v,t,z],10600=[m,r,t,i]....... 
I treid to clear my list listassignee.clear(); after the put instruction but in this case is empty :
My map{10700=[], 10500=[], 10601=[], 10400=[], 10401=[], 10301=[], 10300=[], 10600=[]}

Any suggestion please??

```
public HashMap<String ,ArrayList<String>> MAPAssigneeByissue() throws SQLException
{
    Issue iss =new Issue(); //a class return list of issue
    ArrayList<String> listassignee = new ArrayList<String>();

    HashMap<String ,ArrayList<String>> mapTicketassignee = new HashMap<String ,ArrayList<String>> ();


    Connectionx conn=new Connectionx();


    for (Iterator it = iss.getListissue().iterator();it.hasNext();)
    {
        Object o = (Object) it.next();

        String sql2;
        sql2=" my SQL:retrieve list assignee for each ticket (o.tostring) ";
        ResultSet rs2 = conn.st. executeQuery(sql2);

        while(rs2.next())
        {
            String str=  rs2.getString(1);
            listassignee.add(str);

        }
        mapTicketassignee.put(o.toString(),listassignee);
        //listassignee.clear();
    }

    System.out.println("My map"+mapTicketassignee.toString());
    return mapTicketassignee;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time you iterate trough 
`listassignee = new ArrayList<String>()`

Answer (score 4):

Instead of clearing the list you need to create a new instance of the assignee list for each map value.

Basically this line needs to be inside your loop instead of before:

```
ArrayList<String> listassignee = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Answer (score 1):

I have rewrtten your code to make it work (style issues notwithstanding)

```
public HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> MAPAssigneeByissue() throws SQLException {  
    Issue iss = new Issue(); //a class return list of issue

    HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> mapTicketassignee = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> ();

    Connectionx conn=new Connectionx();

    for (Iterator it = iss.getListissue().iterator();it.hasNext();) {
        Object o = (Object) it.next();

        String sql2 = "my SQL:retrieve list assignee for each ticket (o.tostring) ";
        ResultSet rs2 = conn.st.executeQuery(sql2);

        ArrayList<String> listassignee = new ArrayList<String>();

        while(rs2.next()) {
            String str = rs2.getString(1);
            listassignee.add(str);
        }

        mapTicketassignee.put(o.toString(), listassignee);
    }

    System.out.println("My map"+mapTicketassignee.toString());
    return mapTicketassignee;
}
```

Comment: thank you for the help it worked I have followed Bohemian reply ,shame on me I haven't seen that ,really I was so tired :(